# Show tagged images from facebook on website?

Tags: facebook, api, gallery

I am trying to achieve similar functionality to the one shown here...http://blackmilkclothing.com/collections/leggings/products/circuit-board-grey-leggings

there fan page https://www.facebook.com/blackmilkclothing allows people to hash tag a photo and then populate it on their website like the link above.

Loading a series of tagged images from my facebook fan page  to my website. I am not positive how this is acheived? I am assuming some kind of api process but any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Thanks! All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

See the 'tagged' connection of a Page in the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

It returns a list of objects the page is tagged in, including photos

If you need background knowledge I suggest these links in particular:
Graph API overview: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
Page login: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/

Answer (score 1):

After a good bit of trial and error I've found the most efficient way to query photos tagged to a particular Facebook page is to use [Facebook's FQL interface](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream/) to retrieve a list of stream posts.

With FQL you can limit the queried objects to only those posts containing images (unlike with the higher-level Graph API calls which will return all posts, many of which may not have associated photos), and you'll also have more granular control over composition of the result set.

Keep in mind that Facebook doesn't have true hashtag support (only Facebook pages can be tagged), so to simulate the hashtag support that Black Milk Clothing encourages, you'll need to parse and filter the photo message text yourself.

As an alternative quick and easy solution, I've rolled the results of my efforts into a free online service called [TagTray](http://www.tagtray.com/) -- with TagTray I've added an interface for building and curating hashtag based galleries from Facebook, Instagram, and TwitPic (including application-level Facebook hashtag filtering) that can be framelessly embedded into a site with a few lines of JavaScript.